# epoll timeout configuration in lighttpd

Tags: performance, lighttpd, performance-tuning

Is there a configuration option to tune epoll timeout in lighttpd? 
 I'm developing an embedded Linux (2.6) device, with lighttpd 1.4.30. And I'm observing the following issue: even when the system is idle and there are no web clients connected, the lighttpd wakes up every second (see below). 
/# cat /proc/timer_stats 
Timer Stats Version: v0.2
Sample period: 6.382 s 
   15,   137 alt-ecm          hrtimer_start_range_ns (hrtimer_wakeup) 
   23,     5 events/0         uectl_readerwork (delayed_work_timer_fn) 
   10,   380 db_probe         hrtimer_start_range_ns (hrtimer_wakeup) 
    3,   121 atswitch         hrtimer_start_range_ns (posix_timer_fn) 
    6,   380 db_probe         hrtimer_start (timerfd_tmrproc) 
    **6,   226 lighttpd         sys_epoll_wait (process_timeout)**

the goal is to minimize number of wakeups from idle in the system
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one second timer is needed for:

- the plugin api: each plugin can have a _trigger method, which is supposed to be called every second
- stat_cache_cleanup
- checking every connection for io timeouts

You could increase the timeout for the poll in `src/server.c` around line 1460:

```
if ((n = fdevent_poll(srv->ev, 1000)) > 0) {
```

The value is in milliseconds and is hardcoded to 1000 -> 1 second. But even setting this to 5 or 10 seconds won't help you much imho...

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think it won't help?

Comment: I guess, these actions not required when there is no client connected?

Comment: I said won't help "much". Because 1 wakeup a second is not that bad, considering the things you might break. I guess most plugins won't care about the trigger if there is no client connected, but I didn't try it.